# ERROR: git repository not found at `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`

Tags: julia-pkg

1. question: I have copied one of my julia project from local pc to a cluster using Linux. When I was trying to run `instantiate` in Pkg-REPL, `` ERROR: git repository not found at `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git `` occurred. And I have no idea.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGuef.png)
2. what I have checked: I have entered `status` in Pkg-REPL and it seems everything is well; and there is only one direction *logs* under *~/.julia*
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe66B.png)
3. so what caused the problem and how should I fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you use a proxy?

Answer (score 2):

I finally solve this problem by cloning from `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git` manually.

1. `cd ~/.julila`
2. `mkdir registries` and `cd registries`
3. `git clone https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git` and get a new direction `General`
4. now I can `instantiate` without any error occurred!

I am not still clear why the error occurred when I clone this site automatically using `instantiate`, so this is still a question to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if these could be the causes, but:

- Can the server connect to GitHub?  i.e., can you ping `www.github.com`?  It is possible that a work-based server is hidden behind some firewall.  Of course, quite odd to not allow outbound traffic.
- Also, on your server account, have you had your public key registered with GitHub?  It's been a while since I've had to do this, but you may need to also set your username and e-mail address.  An easy test would be to just try doing a `git clone https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git` on the server and see if that is successful.  If not, perhaps the error message that it gives will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply! I have checked your advices, but it seem that these are not the causes, unfortunately. But I have another question: I "installed" the binary julia file by just unpacking the .tar.gz file and use the binary file directly. But I am not sure how is the ~/.julia direction constructed and updated. I do have a feeling this may be the problem.

Comment: @Jason Hmmmmm, as I have not used Julia before, I don't know how is `~/.julia` is set.  I guess you should check if Julia is properly installed on the server and then once that is confirmed, look into why your program can't be run on the server.  Sorry that I cannot be of more help!